# Perf does not support some performance events

Tags: linux, performance-testing, perf

I want to measure stalled cycles for my application using perf.

When I try: `perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000`

```
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB) copied, 0.218456 s, 2.3 GB/s

Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000':

218.420011 task-clock                #    0.995 CPUs utilized          
25 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
1 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
255 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
821,183,099 cycles                    #    3.760 GHz                    
<not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
<not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
1,526,427,190 instructions              #    1.86  insns per cycle        
292,281,624 branches                  # 1338.163 M/sec                  
1,013,837 branch-misses             #    0.35% of all branches        

0.219551862 seconds time elapsed
```

As you can see, I'm getting  for stalled-cycles* events. I couldn't find a solution or explanation for this online.

My kernel version is 3.2.0-59, perf version is 3.2.54, and my CPU is an i7-3770.

Comment: do you have a file named /sys/devices/cpu/events/stalled-cycles-backend ?

Comment: You probably have to look at the CPU architecture manual and find out matching perf events for stalled-cycles* and set the kernel sources accordingly.

Comment: ["Linux 3.2 released on 4 Jan, 2012"](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.2), that is, more than 2 years ago. Please try it with a newer kernel and perf.

Comment: "do you have a file named /sys/devices/cpu/events/stalled-cycles-backend" - I don't. Infact, I don't have the events folder at all. But I'm seeing some hardware events like instructions and branches.

DO you know why the folder could be missing?

Comment: ""Linux 3.2 released on 4 Jan, 2012", that is, more than 2 years ago. Please try it with a newer kernel and perf" - I also have another machine with kernel 3.8 where it does not work (gives the same <not-supported> output for stalled-cycles-frontend)

Comment: were you abled to solve your issue ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva No, I just switched to a machine where it was working. I have 2 machines on which I don't see the stalled cycles: one i7-3770 with kernel 3.2 and another i7-4770 with kernel 3.8. The machine on which it works is a Xeon E5-2680 with kernel 3.11.

Maybe it's an i7 problem?

Comment: can you provide the cpu family and model provided in /proc/cpuinfo for the two i7 machines ? Moreover have you searched for an events folder on these machines, it sound sstrange that you don't have it.

Comment: @ManuelSelva: For the 1st machine, cpu family = 6, model name = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz. On this machine, I don't have the events folder. On the 2nd machine, I do have the events folder, which contains the following files: {branch-instructions, branch-misses, bus-cycles, cache-misses, cache-references, cpu-cycles, instructions}. For this machine, cpu family is 6, and the model name is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz.

Comment: Sorry but what identify exactly the CPU is the familiny name (a nulber) and the model also a number (not model name).